# Problem migrating to Content Template Builder, twilio WhatsApp

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to migrate to the new content template builder.

This is the code I had before:

```
const message = await client.messages.create({
  from: `whatsapp:${process.env.TWILIO_WHATSAPP_NUMBER}`,
  body: "Message template matching twilio's whatsapp template",
  to: `whatsapp:${reminder.phoneNumber}`,
});
```

And this is the code I have now:

```
const message = await client.messages.create({
  from: `whatsapp:${process.env.TWILIO_WHATSAPP_NUMBER}`,
  // https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/send-templates-created-with-the-content-template-builder
  contentSid: "HXXXXXXXX",
  contentVariables: JSON.stringify(
    {1: "My Name"},
  ),
  to: `whatsapp:${reminder.phoneNumber}`,
});
```

I am following all the information from https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/send-templates-created-with-the-content-template-builder and the contentSid matches the one on my twilio console, but, I keep getting **Twilio Client error:  A text message body or media urls must be specified.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I spotted the issue. You are trying to send the message "directly" `from` the WhatsApp sender. But you need to use a Messaging Service in either the `from` or `messagingServiceSid` fields.

This is also mentioned in the [docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/send-templates-created-with-the-content-template-builder):

> You will also need to first configure a Messaging Service and create your content template.

Comment: It worked when I switched to messagingServiceSid.

Thank you. I think this should be more clear in the docs here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/send-templates-created-with-the-content-template-builder

Answer (score 0):

That is usually related to an outdated version of the Twilio SDK (basically a version before there was the Content Template Builder). Can you make sure to use version 4, or ideally [`4.21.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio)?

Comment: I am using twilio v 4.21.0 npm package, so this is not related to that @iobert

I also tried removing node_modules and reinstalling, but it's not working either